# Why my object has coloured shadow

Tags: shadows

[image]

[image]

Hi. I just started Blender two days ago. And I'm doing tutorials of Blender Guru.

My question is that why my object has coloured shadow?
Can you tell me why and how to make it black shadow?

Thank you.

It is so fun.

Comment: Attached blend can speed up finding solution. Issue probably lays in setup that we don't see from screen. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com looks like sss effect that  is not what should be, so probably some translucency ...

Comment: @vklidu Thank you! But, somehow the link that you gave me does not allow me to upload.... Also, I have no idea how to attach my blend file on this question. Can you help me?

Comment: copy URL of this question (page), go to my link page, drag and drop blend file, check two checkboxes and intp a field "Enter the URL of question ... " (fiels next to UPLOAD button), paste the URL of your question page. After file is uploaded, code is generated, so copy that, go to question page, go to "edit" and paste the code, save.

Comment: Does your table's shader have some subsurface scattering ? If so, you want to set it to 0 or crank it down

Comment: @vklidu Hey! Finally, thank you. I just posted my blender file. Can you teach me what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Gorgious Hi. Ummm... Actually, I have no idea of what the table's shader is. What is it and how can I figure it out?

Comment: Please... Anyone help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Material Properties > Surface > Subsurface and change value to zero.

[image]

Subsurface Scattering (SSS) is used for materials like a skin, milk, etc ... where part of light rays go through a surface and scatters in volume.

Comment: Thank you!!! It really helped. And it's done. Yay!